# Weird Minesweeper bombs-around numbers behaviour

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

So I make a Minesweeper clone for UWP. And, of course, I have the numbers saying how much mines are around. So here's the problem (you can see it on the picture):

[image: Weird behaviour]

The top-left, top, top-right and left field are just missing their numbers. But when I click second time (I didn't implement the prevention to click on the open field the second time) they have their 1 added (the mines are placed differently because I restarted the app to take another screenshot):

[image: top-left, top, top-right and left fields around the bomb have 1, others have 2]

I've tried to work that around by adding 2 instead of 1, but the problem still persists, but is even more wierd.

First click:

[image: still missing]

Second click:

[image: all fields around the mines have 2]

So, finally here go the codez:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Mynesweeper
{
    public class Cell
    {
        public enum CellType
        {
            Safe = 0,
            Bomb = 1,
            Flag = 2,
            FirstClick = 3
        }

        public CellType cellState;
        public bool covered = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MineField : Page
    {

        Cell[,] cells = new Cell[0, 0];
        bool isGenerated = false;
        Button[,] fieldBtns = new Button[0, 0];
        int maxMines = 0;
        int[,] nearbyBombs = new int[0, 0];

        public MineField()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string param = e.Parameter.ToString();
            if (param == "tutorial")
            {
                MinesAmount.Text = "4";
                GenerateLevel(25, 25, 4);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBlock errTxtBlck = new TextBlock() { Name = "ErrorTextBlock", Text = "Error: no or incorrect parameter was specified when navigating to MineField.xaml\r\n\r\nIf you're the player and've downloaded the game through Windows Store, then let me know about this error by contacting me at artyomisflash@mail.ru. If you're not a player then maybe you're me and you have to fix this error.", HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(16, 0, 16, 0), TextWrapping = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextWrapping.Wrap, VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center, FontSize = 24, TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Center };
                MainGrid.Children.Add(errTxtBlck);
                SmileyFace.Text = "...";
            }
        }

        public static int Clamp(int val, int min, int max)
        {
            if (val < min)
            {
                return min;
            }
            else if (val > max)
            {
                return max;
            }
            else
            {
                return val;
            }
        }

        void GenerateLevel(int x, int y, int mines)
        {
            cells = new Cell[x, y];
            StackPanel[] fieldRows = new StackPanel[y];
            fieldBtns = new Button[x, y];
            maxMines = mines;
            nearbyBombs = new int[x, y];
            for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            {
                fieldRows[i] = new StackPanel() { Name = "MineFieldPanelRow" + i, Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
                MineFieldPanelRows.Children.Add(fieldRows[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                {
                    fieldBtns[j, i] = new Button() { Name = "MineFieldButton" + j + "_" + i, Width = 64, Height = 64, Margin = new Thickness(4), Padding = Margin = new Thickness(0) };
                    fieldBtns[j, i].Click += MineFieldButtonClick;
                    fieldBtns[j, i].Content = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uE890", FontSize = 32 };
                    fieldRows[i].Children.Add(fieldBtns[j, i]);
                    cells[j, i] = new Cell()
                    {
                        covered = true
                    };
                    nearbyBombs[j, i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        void PlaceMines()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < maxMines; i++)
            {
                int x = rnd.Next(0, cells.GetLength(0));
                int y = rnd.Next(0, cells.GetLength(1));
                while (cells[x, y].cellState == Cell.CellType.Bomb || cells[x, y].cellState == Cell.CellType.FirstClick)
                {
                    x = rnd.Next(0, cells.GetLength(0));
                    y = rnd.Next(0, cells.GetLength(1));
                }
                cells[x, y].cellState = Cell.CellType.Bomb;
            }
        }

        private void MineFieldButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isGenerated)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldBtns.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fieldBtns.GetLength(0); j++)
                    {
                        if (fieldBtns[j, i] == sender)
                        {
                            cells[j, i].cellState = Cell.CellType.FirstClick;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                PlaceMines();
                isGenerated = true;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    if (cells[j, i].cellState == Cell.CellType.Bomb)
                    {
                        fieldBtns[j, i].Content = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uE783", FontSize = 32 };
                        nearbyBombs[j, i] = -1;
                        if (i - 1 > -1)
                        {
                            if (j - 1 > -1)
                            {
                                nearbyBombs[j - 1, i - 1]+=2;
                            }
                            nearbyBombs[j, i - 1]+=2;
                            if (j + 1 <= nearbyBombs.GetLength(0) - 1)
                            {
                                nearbyBombs[j + 1, i - 1]+=2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (j - 1 > -1)
                        {
                            nearbyBombs[j - 1, i]+=2;
                        }
                        if (j + 1 <= nearbyBombs.GetLength(0) - 1)
                        { 
                            nearbyBombs[j + 1, i]++;
                        }
                        if (i + 1 <= nearbyBombs.GetLength(1) - 1)
                        {
                            if (j - 1 >= 0)
                            {
                                nearbyBombs[j - 1, i + 1]++;
                            }
                            nearbyBombs[j, i + 1]++;
                            if (j + 1 <= nearbyBombs.GetLength(0) - 1)
                            {
                                nearbyBombs[j + 1, i + 1]++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (nearbyBombs[j, i] == 0)
                    {
                        fieldBtns[j, i].Content = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int bombsNearby = nearbyBombs[j, i];
                        fieldBtns[j, i].Content = new TextBlock() { Text = bombsNearby.ToString(), FontSize = 32 };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With XAML part being:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Mynesweeper.MineField"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Mynesweeper"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.Transitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Stats" Margin="16,16,16,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TimeAmount" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Width="64" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,16,0"/>
            <Button x:Name="Smiley" Padding="0" Width="64" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="32" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, LeftPosition, RightPosition">
                <TextBlock x:Name="SmileyFace" Text=":)" TextLineBounds="Tight" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MinesAmount" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="32" Width="64" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="MineFieldPanelRows" Margin="0,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.25" ScaleY="0.25"/>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform> <!-- specially downscaled to fit the whole field on the screen -->
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I really have no idea why this problem exists. Maybe I have made a typo somewhere? Please help!

Comment: pro tip: Alt+PrintScreen takes a screenshot of the focused window only.  So that you can size your window to show only the relevant content.  So that your screenshots are not mostly black space.  So that the relevant content is actually large enough to see.

Comment: the amount of codez is too damn much.

Comment: @MikeNakis I use it often, as you can see, there is no taskbar on scr. 2 & 3

Comment: BTW Clamp function is unnecessary, feel free to ignore it. Forgot to remove it

Comment: you do know that `if (i - 1 > -1)` is equal to `if( i > 0 )`, right?

Comment: @MikeNakis oh, right

Comment: @MikeNakis nope, still doesn't work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135526/discussion-between-artyomisflash-and-mike-nakis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this statement:

```
else if (nearbyBombs[j, i] == 0)
```

You are checking whether a cell has a bomb count of zero as you are still traversing your grid and setting bomb counts, so at the time that this check is being made, not all calculations for that cell have been performed yet.

The solution would be to first do one pass to calculate bomb counts, and once this is complete, *then* do another pass to create buttons and show bomb counts in them.

Comment: btw what helped isn't fix the statement but make a two-pass traversing

Comment: but, but, but, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
                    if (j - 1 > -1)
                    {
                        nearbyBombs[j - 1, i]+=2;
                    }
```

is outside of any block that checks to make sure that `i > 0`.  Therefore, your codez will blowz upz if you ever have a mine at i = 0.  This leads me to believe that your convoluted `if` statements are just plain wrong, and they are just too convoluted to try and find out the precise point where you are messing up your count.  It is like looking for a needle in a haystack, and hardly worth it from the moment that I have already found another mistake.

Let me suggest a different approach to you:

1. Quit using `x` and `y` when you mean `height` and `width`, and certainly quit using `i` and `j` when you mean `x` and `y`.  The convention for names of coordinates in cartesian planes has been 'x' for the horizontal axis and 'y' for the vertical axis since the mid-1600s, ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes)) you do not need to invent a new convention in 2017.
2. Someone told you that you should always use curly brackets even when you have a block that consists of a single statement.  If you think that's wise advise, go ahead and knock yourself out with the curly braces, but at least spare us from curly brace spam here on stackoverflow, where brevity is of importance.
3. Stop using `Random()` before you have even made your code to work.  Place a specific number of bombs at a specific set of coordinates and make sure your stuff works before introducing randomness.
4. Quit that convoluted unreadable cascading zig-zag spaghetti of nested `if` statements and do something much more simple.

Like this:

```
void updateBombCountsAroundBomb( int bombY, int bombX, int height, int width )
{
    for( y = bombY - 1;  y <= bombY + 1;  y++ )
        for( x = bombX - 1;  x <= bombX + 1;  x++ )
            if( y != bombY && x != bombX )
                if( y >= 0 && y < height && x >= 0 && x < width )
                     nearbyBombs[y, x]++;
}
```

Once you have gotten that to work, you may then try to optimize it if you feel like doing so, knowing that if you accidentally break it, you can always revert to a previous version that worked.  (Testing rulez.)

Comment: 2. welp, intellisense almost never told sh*t to me

Comment: k, that still didn't fix the prob, but i'll take your tip